# Google Sheet App Script for finding old urls in IMPORTRANGESs and replace them with new urls

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I developed a document management system built with about 25 Google spreadsheets interlinked with many IMPORTRANGEs. For a new project I have to duplicate the system and relink the spreadsheets.

I can do it like this

```
function replaceEverywhere() {

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

  var textFinder = sheet.createTextFinder('Old_01');
                textFinder.replaceAllWith('New_01');

  var textFinder = sheet.createTextFinder('Old_02');
                textFinder.replaceAllWith('New_02');

  var textFinder = sheet.createTextFinder('Old_25');
                textFinder.replaceAllWith('New_25');

}
```

but I'd like to use a `foreach` with two lists, one with the old urls an the other with the new url.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
function replaceEverywhere() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const o = ["Old_01","Old_02","Old_03"];
  const n= ["ld_01","ld_02","ld_03"];
  o.forEach((e,i) => ss.createTextFinder(e).replaceAllWith(n[i]))
}
```